# Measuring how many times a Button is clicked in Android Application

Tags: android

everyone. I am trying to create a simple application that counts the number of times a button is pressed. I am trying to use a background service to do this. The application is supposed to count how many times the "Press Me!" was clicked and display that number when the Exit button is clicked in the form of a toast. It runs, but it does not show the number of buuton clicks. My code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button  buttonStop, press;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
    press = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonpress);

}


    public void onClick(View src) {
        switch (src.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonpress:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service has started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
          break;
        case R.id.buttonStop:
          stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
          finish();
          break;

        }
    }

public class MyService extends Service {

int count= 0;
MainActivity main;
/**
 * @see android.app.Service#onBind(Intent)
 */
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Put your code here
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

public void onDestroy() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Number of times this button was pressed = " + count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    count = count +1 ;

}
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Exit" 
android:id="@+id/buttonStop">
</Button>  


<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Press Me!" 
android:id="@+id/buttonpress">
</Button>  

</LinearLayout>
```

I would also like to obtain the date, time, latitude and longitude each time the user uses the application. Could somebody help me please? This is my first time building a service and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using a service? Or is this simply to get experience creating a service?

Comment: when should the service created, on clicking the `"Press Me!" ` button or on Activity creation?

Comment: @Engprof: Where are the buttons in Java code?

Comment: Are you creating new services on each button click?

Comment: @Mithun P - the service is supposed to be created on the activity creation. I just want the service to increment the counter every time the "Press Me!" Button is clicked.

Comment: @ Brian D - This is to get the experience of creating a simple service

Comment: @ Brian D - This is to get the experience of creating a simple service.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there!

Three things you forgot to do:

- **Have your MainActivity implement [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)** - If you had used `@Override` before your onClick() method the compiler would've tipped you off. In general, whenever you implement a function that you expect the framework to call, use `@Override` as a sanity check.
- **Attach your MainActivity to your buttons using [View.setOnClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29)** - this actually tells the buttons to call your onClick() method when they are clicked.
- (possibly) **Define your service in your AndroidManifest.xml** - Stick `<service android:name="MyService"/>` inside your  element. If you didn't do this, you could've found out by looking in Logcat (DDMS or Debug perspective). It would've said:

> Unable to start service intent [...]: not found

That's all I had to change in your code, and then the toasts showed up on my screen with the appropriate click count.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the Toast message is displayed, call it on `Exit` button click instead of `onDestroy`.